# JSON in Swift / Error: Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I have a JSON file which looks like this:
[here is a screenshot of my JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZLdm.png)

and I my code is like this:

```
guard let data = data else {
    completionHandler(.failure(.missingResponseData))
    return
}
guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
    let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
        completionHandler(.failure(.invalidJson(message: "data does not contain an array of objects")))
        return
}
do {
    let movies = try results.map {
        try Movie(json: $0)
    }
    completionHandler(.success(movies))
} catch let error as Error {
    completionHandler(.failure(error))
} catch {
    completionHandler(.failure(.other(error)))
}
```

but I get this error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any],  let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
                completionHandler(.failure(.invalidJson(message: "data does not contain an array of objects")))
                return`

Comment: This line `let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]] else {` ?

Comment: Thank you @El Captain V2.0, It works now :)

Comment: glad it helps @Kavoos :)